# Prevent Arrow Keys from changing focus while still allowing functionality of the keys

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code in my project which disables arrow keys completely:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (!msg.HWnd.Equals(Handle) &&
        (keyData == Keys.Left || keyData == Keys.Right ||
         keyData == Keys.Up || keyData == Keys.Down))
        return true;

    if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
        return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

I also have this code after it which I need in order to make it such that the up arrow key counts up.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        int count;

        if (count_lbl.Text.Equals(""))
            count = 0;

        else
            count = Convert.ToInt32(count_lbl.Text);

        count++;
        count_lbl.Text = count.ToString();
    }
}
```

I don't want the arrow keys to change focus to any control, other than the one I initialized my form to, but I still want to be able to use them later on in order to be able to do other things. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: *I don't want the arrow keys to change focus to any control, other than the one I initialized my form to*: what does this mean? Are you referring to the ActiveControl that is set when the Form is first shown? -- Your current code disables the cursor keys when the focus is on any Control other than the Form, so always, if you have a Controls that can take focus on that Form. Can you give a better description of the Form layout and what you want to achieve? E.g., do you want to increment a counter when a specific Control has the focus? BTW, declare that counter as a Field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the "counting" code in `ProcessCmdKey()`?

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (!msg.HWnd.Equals(Handle) &&
        (keyData == Keys.Left || keyData == Keys.Right ||
         keyData == Keys.Up || keyData == Keys.Down)) {
        if (keyData == Keys.Up) {
            int count;

            if (count_lbl.Text.Equals(""))
                count = 0;
            else
                count = Convert.ToInt32(count_lbl.Text);

            count++;
            count_lbl.Text = count.ToString();
        }
        return true;
    }

    if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
        return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```